# One SQL SELECT causing three transactions

Tags: sql, select, transactions, varbinary

Can someone explain why a t-sql `select` is creating three open transactions? Why would it create a transaction at all?

I have a query like this on a table called `jobimage` with no triggers and I am running as a new query in SSMS:

```
  SELECT 1
  FROM [JobImage] AS [j] 
  WHERE ((((([j].[JobId] = 3401639) 
    AND ([j].[DateTime] = '2021-10-27 09:18:05.3441290')) 
    AND ([j].[Comment] = '')) 
    AND ([j].[Stage] = 'Items to Fit'))  
    AND ([j].[Mandatory] = 0))  
    AND ([j].[Image] = 0xFFD8F.....002110103)
```

The issue is with the Image column which is of type `varbinary(max)`, if I leave that out of the select then there is no issue, but if I include it then the query just hangs and if I run sp_whoisactive as it hangs then it reports that the query creates three open transactions which cause blocking issues for several minutes. Using a NOLOCK hint makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it myself. Quite an interesting solution as it may be undocumented; I ran DBCC TRAN too see what this mysterious transaction was and the transaction name was AutoCreateQPStats. The internet does not tell me much about that however I  disabled autocreate statistics on the table and that allowed the SELECT to proceed. It appears that it was trying to create statistics on this *varbinary(max)* column under a transaction